# Bootstrap Popover will Only Load Once. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have a Boostrap `popover` that will only show once and then will not work. What am I missing?

Here is my **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WayBehind/o27wqxz9/)**

Comment: You shouldn't rely on external resources, while having the fiddle is really nice, also including some snippets here would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is due to `$().load();`, actually it's asynchronized and when you `return $("#pop-content").load(...);` for the first time it will return you the contents of `#pop-content` div, and thereafter contents of `#pop-content` set to the result of url you've mentioned in jQuery load, but in your case it's blank.

I've replaced `$(#pop-content).load(...);` with `$(#pop-content).html();` and the results are as expected.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o27wqxz9/58/)

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pop-form').popover({
        html: true,
        title: function () {
            return $("#pop-head").html();
        },
        content: function () {
           var result = '';
           $.ajax({
            url: "your url",
            async: false, 
            success:function(response){
                result = response;
            }
           });

           return result;
        }
    });

    // make popup larger
    var p = $('.popbutton').popover();
    p.on("show.bs.popover", function (e) {
        p.data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "630px");
    });
});
```

Try above code, it should work well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. While your answer is valid for the JS Fiddle, removing the `load()` function will kill the desired result of loading external URL data into the `popover` window. BTW I have added the HTML data inside the `pop-content` for demonstration purposes as the actual `<div>` tag is empty and loaded with external data through the `load()` function.

Comment: Thank you! Your approach is exactly what I have been looking into and while your code is not working for me, I have similar version in place and your answer will be accepted as correct. Thank you again for your help!